# Can not insert date in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert data in MySQL using Python. There is an error when inserted **,_,** and **,:-)** into database.

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

In the codes:

```
emoticons = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/emoticons.txt'
csv_data = csv.reader(open(emoticons, 'rb'))
count = 0
for row in csv_data:
   count = count + 1
   c.execute("INSERT INTO Emoticons (Emotions) VALUES (%s)", row)
db.close()
```

Did I miss something in the codes? Any suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
csv.reader(open(emoticons, 'rb'))
```

reads file as CSV with comma as default separator and returns a list (the `row` variable).

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Emoticons (Emotions) VALUES (%s)", row)
```

awaits a tuple in `row` with exactly one element (because there is one `%s` in the query string).

Your file probably contains commas and these lines will be split into several elements which cannot be formatted into the query.

If you want to insert the whole lines from the file into DB, you don't have to use `csv`:

```
emoticons = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/emoticons.txt'
with open(emoticons, 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Emoticons (Emotions) VALUES (%s)", (row,))
db.close()
```

Comment: Why its waits tuple in row? Its waits string.

Comment: @Denis: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#connection-objects "Why the tuple? Because the DB API requires you to pass in any parameters as a sequence."

Comment: Where you see here db error? She must place % on right place.

Comment: @Denis: The Lord says: "Thou shalt not erect SQL statements with ordinary string formatting, for devastation and data loss awaits thee at its end."